# Change AppDelegate.mm to AppDelegate.swift on React Native 0.71

Tags: ios, react-native, swift5

I encountered the error "A moduleName is required to create an RCTROotView", and then the app was stuck on the startup page. Who can help me? thank you.

**Step**

1. run 'npx react-native init RN0710RC3 --version 0.71.0-rc.3' to create a RN project
2. create 'AppDelegate.swift' 'Bridging-Header.h' and delete 'AppDelegate.mm' 'AppDelegate.h' 'main.m'

**AppDelegate.mm**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.moduleName = @"RN0710RC3";
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
    #if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
    #else
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
    #endif
}

- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
    return true;
}

@end
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: RCTAppDelegate {

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      CommonTheme.currentTheme.primaryColor = .red;
      self.moduleName = "RN0710RC3";
      return self.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions);
  }

  override func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! {
      #if DEBUG
      return RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings()?.jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource: nil)
      #else
      return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsBundle")
      #endif
  }

  func concurrentRootEnabled() -> Bool {
      return true;
  }
}
```

**Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `concurrentRootEnabled` is required by the Objective-C interface `RCTAppDelegate`, so you should put `@objc` to it.

```
@objc func concurrentRootEnabled() -> Bool {
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
should convert into
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

and then the issue should be solved.